Unable to login to MariaDB, as root@localhost, with non root linux user
I have a MariaDB 10.3.13 server installed on Red Hat linux. I can only login to mysql, as root@localhost, through root linux user.
Login to mysql server through non root linux user. It fails
[dave@dbserver ~]$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Login to mysql server through root linux user. It works.
[dave@dbserver ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for dave:
[root@dbserver dave]# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. .....

root database user information:
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT USER,HOST,PLUGIN FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = 'root';
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| USER | HOST      | PLUGIN                |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+

Added 1:
SHOW CREATE USER root@localhost;
-- It returns:
-- CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket USING 'RGFF345'

Why can't I login to mysql, as root@localhost, with dave linux user?

have you run sudo mysql_secure_installation  like described https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-22-04

Why not using sudo before like sudo mysql -u root -p ?

I haven't run sudo mysql_secure_installation. MariaDB 10.3.13 was upgraded from previous versions by rpm files

I can try using sudo mysql -uroot -p. Even though, the question is what is the reason about I can't I login to mysql, as root@localhost, with dave linux user?

look at show create user root@localhost. It look like unix_socket auth based on behaviour. MariaDB 10.4+ can use multiple authentication mechanism so the mysql.user view cannot show all the information. Don't runmysql_secure_installation, its a heap of broken shit.

I updated the post with Added 1. Yes, it shows unix_socket by show create... I run  ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password USING '*4773'; and then I tried to login to mysql by dave linux user and it works. I checked the value from plugin field is empty of mysql.user table for root user
